# DataTables jQuery Plugin - Firefox claims "illegal character"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datatables, cdn

Got something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTable").dataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "order": []
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    th,
    td {
        white-space: nowrap
    }

    TD+TD+TD+TD+TD+TD {
        color: white
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> .... </table>
</body>

</html>
```

This works fine in `Internet Explorer 11`. `Firefox 52` won't load the DataTables Plugin and claims `SyntaxError: illegal character` on the first character of `jquery.dataTables.min.js` loaded from the CDN.
Also tried to save the js file and load it locally, still the same.
What's going on here?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**

So I downloaded the DataTables CSS and JS file and resaved them with encoding `UTF-8 with BOM`. They were saved as `UTF-8` (without BOM) before. Now it's working. Is this a bug in Firefox? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this with:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" charset="utf-8">
```